# Splash screen in Android Application

Tags: android

I am modifying an open source application and want to add a splash screen to it,
Can some one help me in it?

When the application starts a black screen appears for 2 to 3 seconds and then the application appears....
In the code the activity main.xml is started, I have read some forums that the splash.xml file should be created and with the help of threads splash activity and main activity should be executed parallel. Is it the right approach...?

#

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

#

Would it not be possible that I modify main.xml and put the image (splash) in main.xml so that it appears from there?

Comment: yeah you can put your image in your main.xml too. You should post your code to let us get an idea about your problem.

Comment: Yes agree with Lalit and there are plenty of examples available for the splash screen (Android), search in google and let us know if you are getting a problem still.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Use class SplashScreen as under**

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 3000; /* 3 seconds */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            Splashscreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

            Splashscreen.this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,
                    R.anim.splashfadeout);
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
}
```

}

**Add mainfadein.xml & splashfadeout.xml in res->anim folder

### mainfadein.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000">
</alpha>
```

### **splashfadeout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:zAdjustment="top"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1000" >
</alpha>
```

**and add splash.xml just Add an ImageView and set its background as screen & add image of urchoice in layout**

***And make Splashscreen class as Launcher and make all other class as HOME in manifest file***

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to consider that the user might want to quit your app before the splash-delay is over.
So clear any pending runnables/messages when the user exits your app.

Example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409767/best-way-to-have-a-splash-screen-in-an-android-application/12410163#12410163)

Answer (score 3):

Splash activity

```
public class LaunchScreen extends Activity {

  public static final long TIME = 3000;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logo);

    Protocol.getInstance(this);

    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(TIME);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(LaunchScreen.this,MainScreen.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();
  }
}
```

logo.xml file:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/logo"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in AndroidManifest :

```
activity android:name=".LaunchScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainScreen" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but I get the exception after the splash screen is launched...-27 11:02:41.013: E/AndroidRuntime(640): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.app/org.app.appService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? One of my class have already have this activity thing i.e. **bold** `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);`